# Is it possible to add missing symbols to public symbols in a windbg debugging session?

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I am trying to see the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER structure using the 'dt' command in windbg:

> ```
> 0:001> dt ntdll!IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
> **Symbol ntdll!IMAGE_DOS_HEADER not found**
> ```

I searched and found that others have been able to do this:
 [MSDN Blogs   >   Junyoung's Blog    >   Portable Executable File Format on Memory Dump](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/coreinternals/portable-executable-file-format-on-memory-dump)

> ```
> 0:000> dt IMAGE_DOS_HEADER 77c00000
> ntdll!IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
>    +0x000 e_magic          : 0x5a4d ? MZ
>    +0x002 e_cblp           : 0x90
>    +0x004 e_cp             : 3
>    +0x006 e_crlc           : 0
>    +0x008 e_cparhdr        : 4
>    +0x00a e_minalloc       : 0
>    +0x00c e_maxalloc       : 0xffff
>    +0x00e e_ss             : 0
>    +0x010 e_sp             : 0xb8
>    +0x012 e_csum           : 0
>    +0x014 e_ip             : 0
>    +0x016 e_cs             : 0
>    +0x018 e_lfarlc         : 0x40
>    +0x01a e_ovno           : 0
>    +0x01c e_res            : [4] 0
>    +0x024 e_oemid          : 0
>    +0x026 e_oeminfo        : 0
>    +0x028 e_res2           : [10] 0
>    +0x03c e_lfanew         : 232
> ```

Is it possible to add the missing symbol to public symbols of ntdll so that I can access the data structure fields in a windbg debugging session?

This is really weird - I tried the following and got different results on a win7 and on winxp systems -
WinXP:

> ```
> 0:015> dt ntdll!*HEADER*
>           ntdll!_IMAGE_NT_HEADERS
>           ntdll!_IMAGE_FILE_HEADER
>           ntdll!_IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER
>           ntdll!_SLIST_HEADER
>           ntdll!_DISPATCHER_HEADER
>           ntdll!_IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER
> ```

Win7:

> ```
> 0:000> dt ntdll!*HEADER*
>           ntdll!_IMAGE_NT_HEADERS
>           ntdll!_IMAGE_FILE_HEADER
>           ntdll!_IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER
>           ntdll!_IMAGE_DOS_HEADER
>           ntdll!_SLIST_HEADER
>           ntdll!_DISPATCHER_HEADER
>           ntdll!_MM_PAGE_ACCESS_INFO_HEADER
>           ntdll!_WHEA_ERROR_RECORD_HEADER
>           ntdll!_HEAP_USERDATA_HEADER
>           ntdll!_HEAP_USERDATA_HEADER
>           ntdll!_WHEA_ERROR_RECORD_HEADER_VALIDBITS
>           ntdll!_WHEA_ERROR_RECORD_HEADER_FLAGS
>           ntdll!_XSAVE_AREA_HEADER
> ```

So it seems that the _IMAGE_DOS_HEADER symbol is stripped from the public symbols of winxp's ntdll.dll - my question remains - how can I add the symbol if I know the structure to a public symbols dll of a dll I don't have the sources for?

Answer (score 2):

This happens, it can be quite frustrating actually (though they've done a good job cleaning a lot of these up).

You *can* add types to existing PDBs, though it requires that you have the Visual C compiler available (either from Visual Studio or the WDK). I outline the steps in my response here:

http://www.osronline.com/showthread.cfm?link=193747

We're using the kernel there, though you have the same steps. The differences will be:

1) Look for ntdll instead of nt

2) You'll need to write a C file with the definition of the structure that you want.

-scott

Answer (score 0):

you can also check this thread it shows how to add types to

http://www.woodmann.com/forum/showthread.php?10295-Mysteries-of-win32k-amp-GDI&p=72632&viewfull=1#post72632

post # 21

Comment: The link's dead, the post is useless now.

Answer (score -1):

They're not missing, you just don't have your symbol path configured.
Check the following Microsoft [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311503), if that doesn't work, you may have an odder problem.

One way to make sure you're debugging with symbols is the lm command.
The output without debug symbols is likely to look like this:

```
lm
start    end        module name
01000000 01014000   notepad    (no symbols)     
74720000 7476b000   MSCTF      (export symbols)       C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dl
```

Whilee the output for lm with debug symbols will be:

```
lm
start    end        module name
01000000 01014000   notepad    (pdb symbols)          e:\LocalSymbols\notepad.pdb\15800B8231AF4FDE85232D42B267D3E51\notepad.pdb
```

Comment: He sees *some* types in the list, this means he does have the symbols. W/o them, only exported symbols are available.